# Copying filtered data from another WB

Tags: excel, vba

I am a beginner in VBA and I am trying to fix an issue in a code written by someone else. Any help will be much appreciated.

**Background:**
The main macro workbook uses reference data from other excel files. The file path for the reference files are referenced within the main macro workbook in "reference workbooks" tab. They are loaded as Arrays in the macro workbook. For one of the reference data files, I need to sort and filter the data in a particular sheet, then copy all the cells still visible into a sheet in the main macro workbook.

**Issue:**
Currently the macro only copies and pastes the header rows and 42 blank rows. There are more than 1000 rows with data which are not copied. The data in reference files is normally between columns A:BL.

I've shared only the relevant portion of the code for this problem - there are multiple reference files otherwise.

```
Sub dataLoad()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    refpath = wb.path & "\Reference Files\"
    path = ThisWorkbook.path
    Set refiles = Sheets("Reference Workbooks")
    SourceData = refiles.Range("B13").Value 
    wrksht'SourceData = refiles.Range("C13").Value
    
    '1) COPY REFERENCE WORKSHEETS TO WORKBOOK:
    'This allows the template to access the reference materials without having to open and close external documents    

    '1a)Create arrays for the reference workbooks
    Dim fileArr() As Variant
    ReDim fileArr(5)
    fileArr = Array(SourceData)
    
    '1b)Create arrays for the reference worksheets
    Dim wrkshtArr() As Variant
    ReDim wrkshtArr(5)
    wrkshtArr = Array(wrkshtSourceData)
    
    Dim intcount As Integer
    Dim intsheet As Integer
    Dim sheetArr() As Variant
    
    intsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    ReDim sheetArr(intsheet)
    
    For intcount = 1 To intsheet
        sheetArr(intcount) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(intcount).Name
    Next
        
    '1c)A For statement that(i) checks if reference worksheet is already loaded and (ii) copies them to the workbook if not
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 0 To UBound(fileArr)
        testvar = False
        For x = 0 To UBound(sheetArr)
            If testvar = False Then
                If sheetArr(x) = wrkshtArr(i) Then
                    testvar = True
                End If
            End If
        Next x
            
        If testvar = False Then
            Set closedBook = Workbooks.Open(refpath & fileArr(i))
            closedBook.Sheets(wrkshtArr(i)).Copy After:=Workbooks(wb.Name).Sheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
            closedBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Worksheets(wrkshtArr(i)).Visible = xlSheetHidden
        End If
    Next i

    With Worksheets(wrkshtSourceData)
        Dim Datadate As Range: Set Datadate = .Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Date_of_Entry", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        Dim Datastatus As Range: Set Datastatus = .Rows("1:1").Find(What:="FinalStatus", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        
        .Activate
        .UsedRange.Sort Key1:=Range(.Columns(Datadate.Column).Address(Rowabsolute:=False)), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
        .Range(.Columns(Datastatus.Column).Address(Rowabsolute:=False)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Approved"
        
        Sheets.Add.Name = "Database2"
        
        .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        Worksheets("Database2").Paste
        
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Worksheets("Database2").Name = wrkshtSourceData
        
        Worksheets(wrkshtSourceData).Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the answer to this through trial and error. It was simpler than I was making it out to be.
The person who wrote the code forgot to add Selection.AutoFilter in the last section of the code. Updated for your reference between ####.

Thanks a lot to anyone who attempted to resolve this/ posted the answer.

```
 With Worksheets(wrkshtSourceData)
        Dim Datadate As Range: Set Datadate = .Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Date_of_Entry", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        Dim Datastatus As Range: Set Datastatus = .Rows("1:1").Find(What:="FinalStatus", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        
        .Activate
         ####
         Selection.AutoFilter
         ####
        .UsedRange.Sort Key1:=Range(.Columns(Datadate.Column).Address(Rowabsolute:=False)), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
        .Range(.Columns(Datastatus.Column).Address(Rowabsolute:=False)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Approved"
        
        Sheets.Add.Name = "Database2"
        
        .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        Worksheets("Database2").Paste
        
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Worksheets("Database2").Name = wrkshtSourceData
        
        Worksheets(wrkshtSourceData).Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set the range you need using coordinates of the complete shown data. My contributions inside `'#####code` lines

Please let my know if you need some edit, to this answer, because I'm not sure of this.

```
Sub dataLoad()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    refpath = wb.Path & "\Reference Files\"
    Path = ThisWorkbook.Path
    Set refiles = Sheets("Reference Workbooks")
    SourceData = refiles.Range("B13").Value
    wrksht 'SourceData = refiles.Range("C13").Value
    
    '1) COPY REFERENCE WORKSHEETS TO WORKBOOK:
    'This allows the template to access the reference materials without having to open and close external documents

    '1a)Create arrays for the reference workbooks
    Dim fileArr() As Variant
    ReDim fileArr(5)
    fileArr = Array(SourceData)
    
    '1b)Create arrays for the reference worksheets
    Dim wrkshtArr() As Variant
    ReDim wrkshtArr(5)
    wrkshtArr = Array(wrkshtSourceData)
    
    Dim intcount As Integer
    Dim intsheet As Integer
    Dim sheetArr() As Variant
    
    intsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    ReDim sheetArr(intsheet)
    
    For intcount = 1 To intsheet
        sheetArr(intcount) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(intcount).Name
    Next
        
    '1c)A For statement that(i) checks if reference worksheet is already loaded and (ii) copies them to the workbook if not
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 0 To UBound(fileArr)
        testvar = False
        For x = 0 To UBound(sheetArr)
            If testvar = False Then
                If sheetArr(x) = wrkshtArr(i) Then
                    testvar = True
                End If
            End If
        Next x
            
        If testvar = False Then
            Set closedBook = Workbooks.Open(refpath & fileArr(i))
            closedBook.Sheets(wrkshtArr(i)).Copy After:=Workbooks(wb.Name).Sheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
            closedBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Worksheets(wrkshtArr(i)).Visible = xlSheetHidden
        End If
    Next i
    
    '#####################code
    Dim R 'To get the last visible row
    Dim C 'To get the last column
    Dim L 'To get the size of the worksheet
    With Worksheets(wrkshtSourceData)
        
        Dim Datadate As Range: Set Datadate = .Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Date_of_Entry", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        Dim Datastatus As Range: Set Datastatus = .Rows("1:1").Find(What:="FinalStatus", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        
        .Activate
        .UsedRange.Sort Key1:=Range(.Columns(Datadate.Column).Address(Rowabsolute:=False)), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
        .Range(.Columns(Datastatus.Column).Address(Rowabsolute:=False)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Approved"
        
        Dim Sht As Worksheet: Set Sht = Sheets.Add 'Store the sheet into a var...
        Sht.Name = "Database2"
        L = Range("A1").EntireColumn.Rows.Count 'Set the value of L
        R = Range(Cells(L, 1), Cells(L, 1)).End(xlUp).Row '... of R
        C = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column '...and C
        Dim OriginRange As Range: Set OriginRange = .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(R, C)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        'Here get the range of visible cells and store the range into the var
        OriginRange.Copy
        Sht.Activate
     
        Sht.Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        .Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Sht.Name = wrkshtSourceData
        
        Worksheets(wrkshtSourceData).Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End With
    '#####################code
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```